# clang linking error in nix derivation in macos

Tags: rust, linker, clang, rust-cargo, nix

I am beginner to nix package manager and rust, getting an clang error while running nix command.

```
 error: linking with `/nix/store/b9bh3z78rqff14bf0fd78xb07b5cnwdw-clang-wrapper-11.1.0/bin/cc` failed: exit status: 1
   >   |
   >   = note: "/nix/store/b9bh3z78rqff14bf0fd78xb07b5cnwdw-clang-wrapper-11.1.0/bin/cc" "-arch" "arm64" "/private/tmp/nix-build-thumbnailer-lambda-0.1.0.drv-0/rustcELLRbr/symbols.o" "/private/tmp/nix-build-thumbnailer-lambda-0.1.0.drv-0/thumbnailer-lambda/target/aarch64-apple-darwin/release/deps/bootstrap-48dc8c93a7fa887b.bootstrap.5fd5817e-cgu.0.rcgu.o"
```

I am trying to build docker image using nix

```
nix build .#dockerImage --extra-experimental-features "nix-command flakes" --debug
```

below code for docker image in **flake.nix**

```
dockerImage = pkgs.dockerTools.streamLayeredImage {
            name = "my-lambda";
            tag = projectConfig.package.version;
            contents = [ package ];

            config = {
              WorkingDir = "/tmp";
              Cmd = [
                "${package}/bin/bootstrap"
              ];

            };
          };
```

and in packge content have something related to clang

```
 preBuild = with pkgs; ''
            # From: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/1fab95f5190d087e66a3502481e34e15d62090aa/pkgs/applications/networking/browsers/firefox/common.nix#L247-L253
            # Set C flags for Rust's bindgen program. Unlike ordinary C
            # compilation, bindgen does not invoke $CC directly. Instead it
            # uses LLVM's libclang. To make sure all necessary flags are
            # included we need to look in a few places.
            export BINDGEN_EXTRA_CLANG_ARGS="$(< ${stdenv.cc}/nix-support/libc-crt1-cflags) \
              $(< ${stdenv.cc}/nix-support/libc-cflags) \
              $(< ${stdenv.cc}/nix-support/cc-cflags) \
              $(< ${stdenv.cc}/nix-support/libcxx-cxxflags) \
              ${lib.optionalString stdenv.cc.isClang "-idirafter ${stdenv.cc.cc}/lib/clang/${lib.getVersion stdenv.cc.cc}/include"} \
              ${lib.optionalString stdenv.cc.isGNU "-isystem ${stdenv.cc.cc}/include/c++/${lib.getVersion stdenv.cc.cc} -isystem ${stdenv.cc.cc}/include/c++/${lib.getVersion stdenv.cc.cc}/${stdenv.hostPlatform.config} -idirafter ${stdenv.cc.cc}/lib/gcc/${stdenv.hostPlatform.config}/${lib.getVersion stdenv.cc.cc}/include"} \
            "
          '';

          nativeBuildInputs = with pkgs; [
            pkg-config
            llvmPackages_14.libclang
          ];

          buildInputs = with pkgs; [
            imagemagick_custom
          ];

          cargoLock = {
            lockFile = ./Cargo.lock;
          };
```

please help me understand and fix the error.